# What should be the output of this multithreaded code (pthreads - c)?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#define max_thread 5
int d = 0;
pthread_t thread_id[max_thread];

//the thread function definition
static void* thread_func(void* data){
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
        d++;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(){
    int rc, i, n;
    n = 5;
    
    //creating n=5 threads
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        rc = pthread_create(&thread_id[i], NULL, thread_func, NULL);

        if(rc){
            printf("\n ERROR %d \n", rc);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    
    //waiting for the threads to finish execution
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        pthread_join(thread_id[i], NULL);
    }
    
    //printing value of global variable d
    printf("counter = %d\n", d);
    return 0;

}
```

What should be the output of this code? When I execute it, it is giving some arbitrary values (<<500000).

I understand that the critical section(in this case - updating the value of d) of the thread should be locked when it is being executed in a thread. But if I see it as a whole, saying that the variable d is being incremented 5,00,000 times, is it wrong? If I add 1, 500000 times shouldn't the answer be 500000 irrespective of the order of addition?

Please explain where am I going wrong in the concept?

Comment: You do not increment this variable. You read the value from memory, you increment it in the register and you write it back to memory. If another thread is executed in between, your current thread will still write the same value just as if nothing happened in between, losing everything that was done by other threads.

Comment: Without proper protection of access to `d` anything can happen. For instance: Alle 5 threads reads `d` when it is zero. Then each thread increments it's local copy of `d` and then they one-by-one writes the value back. Now `d` is only 1 despite the 5 increments.

Comment: Understanding threads comes with understanding race conditions and how to prevent them with semaphores/mutex. That's very basic stuff - so you need to study threads before using threads.

Comment: You probably need to read more about pthreads, in particular about synchronization with [mutex](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mutex-lock-for-linux-thread-synchronization/)-es. See on Linux [pthread_mutex_init](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_mutex_init.3p.html), [pthread_mutex_lock](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_mutex_lock.3p.html) and `pthread_mutex_unlock`

Comment: And on the more advanced topic of optimization, the loops will not get optimized to `d = 100000` as one might expect and this is because `d` has external linkage and cannot be assumed be unchanged between writes, since a function in a different translation unit could have updated it. That has everything to do with linkage and nothing to do with threads. Had you made the variable `static` then the compiler would unlikely be smart enough to understand that multiple threads may access the variable from the same callback. And in order to prevent optimization then, you'd have to use `volatile`.

Comment: @Lundin i do know about the locking concept. But I was wondering what would happen if this would be done without lock, i wrote that in the question as well

Comment: @Lundin *And in order to prevent optimization then, you'd have to use `volatile`.*  And I'll point out that would still fail to make `d++` atomic, and that means there would still be a race condition and undefined behavior.

Comment: @AryamanGupta Well you haven't quite grasped the meaning of race conditions - it does not just mean "order of execution is not guaranteed" but "data loss/corruption may happen".

Comment: @AndrewHenle Protection against incorrect optimization and protection against race conditions aren't really related. Hence why I posted 2 different comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code [invokes undefined behavior per **5.1.2.4 Multi-threaded executions and data races**, p25](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.4p25):

> The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.

As already noted in the comments, `d++` is not an *atomic* operation since it involves at least three separate steps:  read the value from memory, increment the variable, then store the new value into memory.  Trying to perform that series of operations from multiple threads results in a race condition per 5.1.2.4p25 and invokes undefined behavior.

Thus there is no "correct" result.

Comment: so for some atomic process this would work fine? If yes, can you give example of some atomic process? (can just reading a value from the memory and printing it in the threads be considered as an atomic process? The would be quite useless, but still.)

Comment: @AryamanGupta  You could, for example, make `d` an [atomic type](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.17).  Or protect it with a mutex or other synchronization object.

Comment: ... though protecting (all) access to `d` with a mutex resolves the data race not by making the accesses atomic in the sense the spec is using, but rather by ensuring that of every pair of accesses to it, one "happens before" the other.